# php convert user image to jpg

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert all images to JPG format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060835/how-to-convert-all-images-to-jpg-format-in-php)

I'm trying to pass the username into the filename and have the file end with .jpg  So the output would be "user-mycoolnewimage.jpg".  Any suggestions on how to do this as currently is changes to "randnumber-mycoolnewimage.png" which isn't what I want.  The random number doesn't help server logs and the image needs to end with jpg since it's being converted.

```
$file = rand(0, 10000000).$_FILES['t1']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
    if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0)) {
        $picture = fread($fp,filesize($file));
        fclose($fp);
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        imagejpeg($image, $file, 70);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $tag1 = '<img src="'.$file.'" alt="" class="default" />';
        //unlink($file);        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `basename` (documented [here](https://www.php.net/basename))

One thing you could do is rework a bit your script to have something where you create two different `$file` variables, one holding the initial `png` and the other one holding the `jpeg` path. You will also need to `unlink` your `png` once done:

```
$source = $username . "-" . $_FILES['t1']['name'];
$destination = $username . "-" . basename($_FILES['t1']['name']) . ".jpg";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'], $source)) {
    if($fp = fopen($source,"rb", 0)) {
        $picture = fread($fp,filesize($source));
        fclose($fp);
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
        imagejpeg($image, $destination, 70);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $tag1 = '<img src="'.$file.'" alt="" class="default" />';
        unlink($source);        
     }
}
```