# How can I convert uploaded images to JPG format

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP file upload script:

```
$path = "uploads/";
$actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name);
```

How can I save the uploaded image in JPG format?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060835/how-to-convert-all-images-to-jpg-format-in-php

Comment: are you wanting to convert any uploads to .jpg or only allow .jpg uploads?

Comment: @diggersworld i want convert any uploads images to .jpg

Comment: What has your research shown up so far?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$path = "uploads/";

$img = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
$dst = $path . $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];

if (($img_info = getimagesize($img)) === FALSE)
  die("Image not found or not an image");

$width = $img_info[0];
$height = $img_info[1];

switch ($img_info[2]) {
  case IMAGETYPE_GIF  : $src = imagecreatefromgif($img);  break;
  case IMAGETYPE_JPEG : $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img); break;
  case IMAGETYPE_PNG  : $src = imagecreatefrompng($img);  break;
  default : die("Unknown filetype");
}

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($tmp, $dst.".jpg");

?>
```

Comment: This gives me a black image

Answer (score 2):

Make sure GD Library is installed and use it to convert gif or png to jpg like

```
    if ($_FILES["photoimg"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["photoimg"]["type"] == "image/png" || $_FILES["photoimg"]["type"] == "image/gif" )
    {
      if ($_FILES["photoimg"]["type"] == "image/png" || $_FILES["photoimg"]["type"] == "image/gif" )
      {
       imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["photoimg"]["tmp_name"])), "converted.jpg");
       $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
       move_uploaded_file("converted.jpg", $path.$actual_image_name);
      }
      else
      {
        $actual_image_name = time().$session_id.".".$ext;
        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name);
      }
    }
```

Comment: i want allow png and gif, but png and gif should be convert to jpg

Comment: Use GD library to convert   png and gif to jpg