# PHP image copying files to another directory and changing their extension

Tags: php, file-copying

I have the following PHP code to copy files from a folder to another i.e. from the source to the destination.

```
//Copy files to new destination
$img_input = "temp_images/".$foldername."/input";
$img_org = "temp_images/".$foldername."/output/".$foldername."/originals";
$img_scan = glob("$img_input/*.*");

foreach($img_scan as $img_scans){
    $img_scans_to_go = str_replace($img_input,$img_org,$img_scans);
    copy($img_scans, $img_scans_to_go);
}
```

The source `$img_input` contains mixed format images. Now I want the destination files `$img_org` to have `.jpg` image format. How can I do this?

I tried changing `$img_scan = glob("$img_input/*.*");` to `$img_scan = glob("$img_input/*.jpg");` but only jpg files will copy. The other files wouldn't copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP to convert your images to JPG from other file types, have a look at some of these:
[PHP's GD lib - will let you open various file types and save as JPEG](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Existing stack posts are around, like here: [How to convert all images to JPG format in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060835/how-to-convert-all-images-to-jpg-format-in-php)

Comment: Thanks. In this case I prefer just changing the extension.

Comment: Literally just changing the file's extension? Your prerogative... Look up PHP's rename() function and put it after your copy() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php (the PHP manual is your best mate)

Comment: I tried `rename ($img_org .'/*.*',$img_org .'/*.jpg');` but it didn't work. Any help please?

Comment: I don't think `rename` accepts more than one file like `glob` does... After your `copy()` line, put something like this: `rename($img_scans_to_go, $img_scans_to_go . '.jpg');` - that should do a quick and nasty job of putting `.jpg` onto the end of your **copied** files

Comment: They came really nasty names lol such as picture01.jpeg.jpg, picture02.gif.jpg, picture05.jpg.jpg

Comment: Yeah, take the extension off the old file first and replace it if you want to. I don't recommend doing this at all though... You should be **converting** files, not just renaming them...